# PySpark - TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to execute below PySpark code and getting the error
`TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable.`.
Can somebody help me to understand what is wrong with my code?

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F                                                   
from pyspark.sql.window import *                                                        
from pyspark.sql.functions import lead, add_months, trunc, max                       
appName = "Example"                                                                    
master = "local[*]"                                                                    
spark = (
  SparkSession
  .builder
  .appName(appName)
  .master(master)
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
)
df = spark.read.table("user.test")
generate_months = (
  df
  .select(
    "DP_AD_ACCT_NBR",
    "DP_AD_CCY_CDE",
    "DP_AD_CURR_BAL",
    "DP_AD_LST_MDFSN_DATE",
    F.lead("DP_AD_LST_MDFSN_DATE", 1, F.current_date()).over(
      Window.partitionBy("DP_AD_ACCT_NBR","DP_AD_CCY_CDE")
      .orderBy ("DP_AD_LST_MDFSN_DATE")
    ).alias("next_date")
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is with `F.lead()` call. Third parameter (default value) is not of `Column` type, but this is just some constant value. If you want to use `Column` for default value use `coalesce()`:

```py
F.coalesce(
  F.lead("DP_AD_LST_MDFSN_DATE").over(
    Window.partitionBy("DP_AD_ACCT_NBR","DP_AD_CCY_CDE")
    .orderBy ("DP_AD_LST_MDFSN_DATE")
  ),
  F.current_date()
).alias("next_date")
```

Offset default value is 1 so you can omit it.